# No booting after changing from UEFI to Legacy and back to UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

because I wanted to try and boot from a USB stick, I changed the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy. Since booting from the USB stick didn't worked (the USB stick didn't showed up as a bootable device), I changed back to UEFI boot mode.
However this broke my complete installation. Ubuntu is not longer showing up as a boot option and Windows says that there are errors and tries to perform a self repair which fails.

Before changing to legacy for trying to live boot from the USB stick, I had a working dual boot setup with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

Has anyone a suggestion how to fix this mess?

Comment: It should not affect your installation if you switch from UEFI to Legacy BIOS. Nothing is being written to your drive. You will just get an error like *failed to find system boot* or similar. When you switch back it should boot as it was. So you must have done something else. Without a working system, or a workable USB stick it's going to be difficult to tell what went wrong. You don't switch to Legacy to boot from a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks for your replie. I can try to boot Ubuntu from a live Usb stick. Any suggestion what I can try then to make Ubuntu show up again in the boot option menue?

Comment: If you can get live Ubuntu up and running, open terminal and run command `sudo parted -l`. Then edit your question and paste the output into it.

Comment: The setting in UEFI is only for installed systems. How you boot external drives, depends on which entry in one time UEFI boot menu you select UEFI:USB or USB where USB may be name or label of USB external drive.